# Nodejs memory management

Tags: node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am starting learning Nodejs and trying to understand the way it manages memory.
I know there is a thing called "GC"(Garbage collector)

I try following small code with Express JS:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
    let used = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
    console.log(`The script uses approximately ${Math.round(used * 100) / 100} MB`);
})
app.get('/a', (req, res) => {
    var array = Array(1e7).fill("a");
    delete array;
    let used = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
    console.log(`The script uses approximately ${Math.round(used * 100) / 100} MB`);

    res.send('Hello World!')
})
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

I added 2 routes.
The first route has nothing special, just a piece of code to print how much memory is using.

In the second route, I create a huge array and I delete it after that.

I call the first route. I got:

`The script uses approximately 5.87 MB`

Then I call the second route, I got:

`The script uses approximately 82.2 MB`

Then I refresh the first route, I got:

`The script uses approximately 4.36 MB`

Then I refresh the second route again. I got:

`The script uses approximately 80.6 MB`

From now on, no matter how many time I refresh the first route, I always got:

`The script uses approximately 80.65 MB`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVTfZ.png)

I know the "delete" keyword only break the reference, it does not really free the memory immediately.

But how about GC? What it is doing?
I wait for more than 10mins and try the first route, it show almost the same result (> 80MB)

Can someone explain why the memory is not reduced?
Thanks for your help

Comment: `delete` is for removing properties from an object.  It's not for deleting a local variable - That is NOT what it does..  See this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) for details. Set the local variable to `null` if you want the array to be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @jfriend00 when the function finishes executing and the stack frame is cleared, the array should be GC-able anyway, since it's not referenced anywhere else.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah and that's not what this question is about.  The OP is trying to measure immediate memory usage changes which won't happen with `delete` or setting it to `null` as that isn't how GC works.  My previous comment should have the word "immediately" at the end, but alas I can't edit that comment any more.

Comment: @jfriend00 the scenario is that eventually the first route is called and yet it still appears that the heap memory is used by the array that only exists while the second route is being processed..

Comment: If it's still there in 2 hrs, then it's probably a measurement problem, not actually a memory usage problem.   The memory may still belong to the process, but is available for resuse.  If you run the same request 1000 times separated with several seconds between requests, does your server memory usage continue to up and up on every request and stay raised really high after everything is done.

Answer (score 0):

Large objects always falls into Generation 2 of a "garbage collection" that's why such objects can "live" much longer even without references than small objects.

In addition to `delete array;` you can do `array.length = 0;` beforehand.

Comment: `array = null` would be better.  `delete array` does not delete a local variable at all.  `delete` is for removing properties from an object, not for deleting local variables.  `delete` has no use in this example of trying to free memory used by a local variable.

Comment: for local variables there is no need (if they don;t store unmanaged resources) to do anything usually.

Comment: Agreed, there is no need.  So, why are you saying ***"In addition to `delete array;` you can do `array.length = 0;`"***?  When the first does NOTHING at all and the second is not needed here.  Ultimately, this question needs to be explained by delving into the timing of garbage collection and also in what `process.memoryUsage().heapUsed` reports.  An answer to the question has absolutely to do with `delete array` or with `array.length = 0`.  That's my point here.

Comment: I just forgot about useless `delete somevar`. My bad. I just thought `array.length = 0` can help to free memory a liittle bit faster.

Comment: @jfriend00 As I mentioned in my question, I know `delete` does not free the memory immediately. I tried `array = null` too. But my question is why that unused variable live for long time? Why GD does not collect it?

Comment: @Anatoly So what if my website has huge traffic? The memory will be increasing crazy. There must be a way to make GC work immediately right?

Comment: @NHT - There is not a production way to make GC run immediately or to control it in any way.  node.js does have a command line argument that exposes a `global.gc` object that lets you manually run GC, but that is usually for troubleshooting, not something you do in production.  If memory starts to run low and GC hasn't been able to run (server hasn't been idle), then GC will take more cycles and will run to keep you from running out.  There are different types of GC cycles, but in general they will run when your node.js server is otherwise idle (so as not to slow anything else down).

Comment: @jfriend00 I see. But in this example, my server is super simple. What makes it so busy? I wait for even more than 2hrs and it is still there. If my website is big and has huge traffic , the memory will be increasing crazy

Comment: GC does not free memory is there is enough of it. It works so due to performance reasons. Try t allocate more memory several times using the same route with an array